# Select which popup opens on a first click on a browser action

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I developed a chrome extension which uploads the data to my API.

It follows with `signin` page and `data-upload` page. As for this functionality, everything works fine.

The problem is when I click on the extension for the first time, it doesn't open. And on 2nd time clicking it opens. I need my extension to open immediately when user clicks the extension. I am not aware how to do that.

Here is my code:

`manifest.json`

```
{
  "content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
    "js": [ "js/dataupload.js", "js/signin.js" ]
    }
  ],
  "name": "upload",
  "version": "1.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Quick access to upload data",
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'",
  "permissions": [
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "https://myapi.com/*",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/*",
    "management",
    "tabs"
    ],
  "icons": {
    "128": "images/icon.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["js/background.js"]
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Upload APP",
    "default_icon": "images/icon.png"
  },
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
}
```

`background.js`

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    if (window.localStorage.getItem('user_api_key')) {
        chrome.browserAction.setPopup({popup: "upload.html"});
    }
    else{
        chrome.browserAction.setPopup({popup: "signin.html"});
    }
});
```

Comment: Share some code with us, otherwise we cannot do much...

Comment: Actually I have my project code and I dint wrote any code for opening the extension immediately after user clicking. Please tell me what code should I share

Comment: First of all your manifest, and maybe your pupup's html/scripts. If you're using the `chrome.browserAction` method in your background script you should share a snippet of it too. In other words: anything regarding the browser action and its popup.

Comment: I have updated the code. Let me know is that enough or still I need to add anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code works as expected. First click is caught by `chrome.browserAction.onClicked` that sets what happens on the next click.

There [will be soon](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=436489) a direct solution in form of a `chrome.browserAction.openPopup` function, but **it's not in Stable yet**.

So for now you have to reorganize the logic, as you can't open a popup if it doesn't happen immediately on click. You should set `upload.html` as the default popup in the manifest, and then inside `upload.html` check the condition and redirect if needed. Note that `localStorage` is shared between background and popup.

So, manifest:

```
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Upload APP",
    "default_icon": "images/icon.png",
    "default_popup": "upload.html"
  },
```

`upload.html`'s code:

```
if (!window.localStorage.getItem('user_api_key')) {
    window.location = chrome.runtime.getURL("signin.html");
}
```

Comment: What you said is okay. But by setting default_popup in manifest file, even after logout the upload.html will be showcased. But after logout the signin.html should be shown.

Comment: How are you doing the logout? The condition must return false; adapt it if you're not simply clearing `localStorage` key

Comment: Hey Xan, What you said was excellent. I made some edits on your answer. WIth that edit it works fine. Thanks Xan.

Comment: I don't like your edit: it results in redirects more often, as the normal state is being signed in.

Comment: But with your answer I dint meet my question. So I just modified your code and tested. It works fine for me so I edited.

Comment: Okay, let's get this straight. As I understand, normally your user would be signed in, and rarely signed out. So it's best to assume he/she is signed in, open the appropriate page, and redirect if it's not true. You just flipped the condition and page, which works the same, except it redirects more often - and it looks bad.

Comment: If you think that your inverted-logic approach is better, post it as another answer. But I will not accept this edit for reasons I explained.